# How to get input values using functional component with useState

Tags: reactjs

When using a class based component I could get all of the field inputs by simply doing this:

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Then in the actual form element I had:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

I am now using a functional component and it doesn't seem that easy.

Having to add a different onChange handler to each form input is a pain eg:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
onChange={event => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
onChange={event => setLastName(event.target.value)}
onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
```

Is there a way to achieve the below using a functional component?

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine both firstName and lastName into one state and set each property based on the event.target.name. The spread operator preserves the current state and overwrites with the incoming update.

```
const [name, setName] = useState({
  first: '',
  last: ''
});    

handleChange = event => {
  setName({
    ...name, 
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```